# Does $b^Tx = x^Tb$ always hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transpose

**Does $b^Tx = x^Tb$ always hold?**
(assume that $b^Tx$ can be defined )
I am studying some computer science and it seems like this property holds for transpose matrices but I am not sure.  I found that :
$$(Ax)^T = x^TA^T$$
Also when we work with inequalities , can we take the transpose of the left side for instance like that (?):
$$ Ax \leq b \implies x^TA^T \leq b $$
I think it holds something like that (we can transpose both sides, like working with powers ):
$$Ax \leq b  \implies x^TA^T \leq b^T$$

Can you confirm or reject those?

Comment: It depends on what $b$ and $x$ are ...

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: if $x$ and $y$ are vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then notice that $x^\top y=y^\top x=x\cdot y$, as the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is symmetric